# What is the correct way to delete a pointer from a list (Using Qt)

Tags: c++, qt

Let say I have a class `MyClass`.

So now I have these structures

```
QList<MyClass*> mylist;
QHash<qint32,MyClass*> myhash;
```

So I add to them, and, at given point I want to delete one fo the items.

If I just do:

```
mylist.removeAt(i);
myhash.remove(key);
```

I'm guessing that this does not free up memory correctly (as only the pointer is deleted).

Would something like this be more correct:

```
MyClass *m = mylist.at(i);
delete m;
mylist.removeAt(i);
```

?

Comment: Maybe `auto p = myList.takeAt(i); delete p;`? `QList::takeAt()` just removes a pointer from container, but doesn't delete it. You have to do it yourself, if needed.

Comment: It's difficult to point to the right way to do this because it's not clear where you're allocating. You have to define the scope of life of your objects. A list of pointers doesn't always mean you have to delete the object underneath. Maybe you're just collecting a list to do some test on the members. Are you allocating the classes just to put them in a list, do something to them, then delete them? Maybe then you don't need pointers. Or maybe you should use smart pointers to manage memory for you.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist. Actually the places where I've runned into this problem the structure that maintains the pointes lasts the lifetime of the application. It is is a private variable that forms part of a class that it is only  instatiated once.  The pointer is obtained from a library function that returns a pointer. I use to both access and process data. But at a given point of the program they are not necessary anymore. So I delete them to free up memory. Does this help you?

Comment: If the library is returning pointers **and giving you ownership of these pointers** (meaning that you're responsible for deleting them), then it's probably best to put them in a `unique_ptr` or some of [Qt's smart pointers](https://wiki.qt.io/Smart_Pointers) and not worry about them yourself. Then, clearing that list will fix this for you and delete the objects underneath.

Comment: Maybe my question is a bit off topic, but is it a good idea to use `list`-type structure in a place where you'd need random access?

Comment: @JohnCvelth `QList` is not like `std::list`. It has constant access time complexity.

Comment: @JohnCvelth. Most of the time I actually use the hash.

Comment: @JohnCvelth Thanks! I'll look into it. I don't know much about smart pointers. I'll read up on it

Comment: have you considered using smart pointers or QSharedPointer?